# Solr Sunspot issue with rails 5 RSolr::Error::ConnectionRefused: Connection refused

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, ruby-on-rails-5, sunspot-solr

Recently we moved an application from rails 4 to rails 5.1.6
The issue which we are facing is that on starting the sunspot it shows as sunspot has started. But on reindex or on doing any database action, we are getting connection refused error

```
production:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/default
development:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: INFO
    path: /solr/default
test:
  solr:
    hostname: localhost
    port: 8983
    log_level: WARNING
    path: /solr/test
```

This is the process which we followed
https://gist.github.com/1v/8a04e74ed1e86d8c52cf007f77b178be

Can anyone please help us on this

Comment: can you check on solr port, whether it is working or not? Means can you try querying on `http://localhost:8983/solr/query?q=test` for testing purpose

Answer (score 1):

`Error 503 connection refused` is usually linked to the following issues :

- Solr server isn't actually launched (sunspot might tell you it is, don't listen to it, it is often a lie). To check if it was really launched, do `rake sunspot:solr:start` twice. It should fail the second time.
- Solr server is launched on the wrong environment. Execute `RAILS_ENV=your_environment bundle exec rake sunspot:solr:start`. Put the RAILS_ENV at beginning, not at the end.
- You solr server is launched twice on 2 different environment. You might even have a file write.lock in your solr folders. Delete this file if you have it. Check with `ps aux | grep solr` that you only have one solr running.

Usually, we just kill the solr processes and relaunch them, it is enough 90% of the time.

Edit : Another way of checking if solr actually run is to type `rake sunspot:solr:run` which run the process in the shell instead of the background. If it fails you should be able to see why.